# Rock Paper Scissors -> output is inconsistent with the result

Tags: javascript

**Background:**

I am a coding newbie, started learning JS from fresh about a week ago. I have created a rock paper scissors game (in early stages) with a Simple HTML/CSS UI, and Javascript with a bit of DOM manipulation. I have been trying to figure out why the code isn't working here for some time now, but I would really appreciate any feedback even if small. Thank you.

**The Problem:**

1. When I click either Rock, Paper or Scissors, shown below, I would get any of the three responses randomly if i repeatedly press the same option:

   - "You Win this round! ..."
   - "You Lost this round! ..."
   - "It's a tie!..."

posted under `<h3 class=".message">` element.

[image: UI]

2. `computerChose = computerPlay();` variable does not change output from initial choice even if I repeatedly press the options. I can't seem to figure out how to "reset" the computer choice.

**But the Scores added for both User and Computer are fine, although it corresponds to which of the output in `<h3 class=".message">` element is shown.**

```js
//Counts the scores for player and computer
let playerScoreCounter = 0;
let computerScoreCounter = 0;

//3 Btn event listeners for each round, each choice
const rockBtn = document.querySelector(".rock");
rockBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let result = playRound("Rock");
  if (result == "win") {
    playerScoreCounter++;
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = `You win this round! Rock beats ${computerChose}`;
  } else if (result == "loss") {
    computerScoreCounter++;
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = `You lost this round! ${computerChose} beats Rock`;
  } else if (result == "tie") {
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = `It's a tie! You both selected Rock`;
  }
  document.querySelector(".your-score").textContent = `Your Score: ${playerScoreCounter}`;
  document.querySelector(".computer-score").textContent = `Computer Score: ${computerScoreCounter}`;
  console.log(computerChose);
});

const paperBtn = document.querySelector(".paper");
paperBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let result = playRound("Paper");
  if (result == "win") {
    playerScoreCounter++;
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = `You win this round! Paper beats ${computerChose}`;
  } else if (result == "loss") {
    computerScoreCounter++;
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = `You lost this round! ${computerChose} beats Paper`;
  } else if (result == "tie") {
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = `It's a tie! You both selected Paper`;
  }
  document.querySelector(".your-score").textContent = `Your Score: ${playerScoreCounter}`;
  document.querySelector(".computer-score").textContent = `Computer Score: ${computerScoreCounter}`;
});

const scissorsBtn = document.querySelector(".scissors");
scissorsBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let result = playRound("Scissors");
  if (result == "win") {
    playerScoreCounter++;
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = `You win this round! Scissors beats ${computerChose}`;
  } else if (result == "loss") {
    computerScoreCounter++;
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = `You lost this round! ${computerChose} beats Scissors`;
  } else if (result == "tie") {
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = `It's a tie! You both selected Scissors`;
  }
  document.querySelector(".your-score").textContent = `Your Score: ${playerScoreCounter}`;
  document.querySelector(".computer-score").textContent = `Computer Score: ${computerScoreCounter}`;
})

//Functions for play

const computerChose = computerPlay();

function computerPlay() {
  const computerChoice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
  const computerChooses =
    computerChoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoice.length)];
  return computerChooses;
}

function playRound(playerSelection) {
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();

  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    return "tie";
  } else if (
    (playerSelection == "Rock" && computerSelection == "Scissors") ||
    (playerSelection == "Paper" && computerSelection == "Rock") ||
    (playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Paper")
  ) {
    return "win";
  } else if (
    (playerSelection == "Rock" && computerSelection == "Paper") ||
    (playerSelection == "Paper" && computerSelection == "Scissors") ||
    (playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Rock")
  ) {
    return "loss";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container-1">
    <header>
      <h1>Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
      <h2>Play against the Computer</h2>
    </header>
  </div>

  <div class="container-2">
    <div class="choices-block rock-choice-block">
      <i class="fas fa-hand-rock fa-10x"></i>
      <button class="btn rock">Rock</button>
    </div>
    <div class="choices-block paper-choice-block">
      <i class="fas fa-hand-paper fa-10x"></i>
      <button class="btn paper">Paper</button>
    </div>

    <div class="choices-block scissors-choice-block">
      <i class="fas fa-hand-scissors fa-10x"></i>
      <button class="btn scissors">Scissors</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-3">
    <div class="message-box">
      <h3 class="message"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="score">
      <h3 class="your-score">Your Score: 0</h3>
      <h3 class="computer-score">Computer Score: 0</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="results-box">
      <h1 class="results"></h1>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is the problem here? If the scores are shown correctly and the outputs are showing correctly, what is wrong?

Comment: To give an example, I am continuously pressing "ROCK", but output for h3 class="message" element is either of these three, in random fashion: "You Win this round! Rock beats [option]", "You Lost this round! [same option] beats Rock", and "It's a tie!...",

Comment: In other words, output to the h3 message element is inconsistent.

Comment: Oh i apologise,, what I meant is it is giving illogical statements: e.g. "
You lost this round! Rock beats Paper". Rock cannot beat paper.

Comment: Do you think it's because the computer keeps the choice of the previous round or something like it?

Comment: The problem, in a nutshell, is that in your output, you are always outputting the value of the global variable `computerChose`. This is randomly generated when the page first loads, but is never updated afterwards - and bears no relation to what is actually chosen inside the `playRound` function.

Comment: Yes, i do think it's keeping the previous choice even for subsequent rounds, but I would have thought it should rerun computerPlay(); again since (I think) it's called each time at playRound().

Comment: Thank you @Robin